# A function that inserts element y before first occurrence of x?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I am trying to write a function that, given the list **l**, element **x** that exists in the list, and an element to insert **y**: insert element y before the first occurrence of the element x, in list l. If element x does **not** exist in the list, then leave the list unchanged.

I am having a lot of trouble with this one and would appreciate any suggestions.

This is what I tried ('n' is the first occurrence of element x):

```
insertSpecial :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insertSpecial let (ys,zs) = splitAt n xs in ys ++ [y] ++ zs
```

Comment: Should that be `insertSpecial n y xs = let (ys,zs) = splitAt n xs in ys ++ [y] ++ zs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
insertSpecial :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insertSpecial x y []              = []
insertSpecial x y (a:as) | a == x = y:a:as
insertSpecial x y (a:as)          = a : insertSpecial x y as
```

This approach uses a general method known as **recursion**. This means that the task at hand is broken down into one or several **base case(s)**, for which the result can be defined easily, and a general case which can be solved by breaking down the work into parts. In the general case the function is then called *recursively* on the smaller task. The goal is to eventually end up in a base case at which point the work is done. See also [this part from *Learn you a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion).

For `insertSpecial` we can define two base cases:

1. If the list is empty it doesn't contain the element we're looking for and we want to leave the list unchanged in this case, so we simply return an empty list. We're done.
2. If the list is not empty **and** the first element is the one we are looking for we stick `y` in front of this list and return that. Again we're done.

That leaves us with the case where the list is not empty but the first element is not the one we are looking for. In this case we break up the work (the list) in two parts: the first element and the rest of the elements. We put the first element in front of the list that is returned by calling `insertSpecial` on the rest of the list. This is where the recursion happens: a call of `insertSpecial` calls itself.

One thing that is maybe a little difficult to understand about this is how the last case produces a list that only differs from the original list by inserting an element at the right place. Let's consider an example. Say we have the list

```
['h','e','l','o']
```

Note that in Haskell, regular strings are just lists of characters so `['h','e','l','o'] == "helo"`. Also note that `['h','e','l','o']` is really syntactic sugar for `'h':'e':'l':'o':[]`. (`:` takes an element and a list and prepends that element to the list. it is also called *cons*).

Now let's insert the missing `'l'` in front of the `'o'`:

```
 insertSpecial 'o' 'l' "helo"
```

Since `"helo"` is not empty `'h'` is bound to `a` and `"elo"` is bound to `as` (furthermore, `'o'` is bound to `x` and `'l'` is bound to `'y'`). Since `a == 'h' /= 'o' == x` we are in the third case, so

```
  insertSpecial 'o' 'l' ('h':"elo") = 'h' : insertSpecial 'o' 'l' "elo"
```

Now with `insertSpecial 'o' 'l' "elo"` we again fall into the third case (`"elo"` is not empty and `'o' /= 'e'`):

```
 insertSpecial 'o' 'l' ('e':"lo") = 'e' : insertSpecial 'o' 'l' "lo"
```

Which again leads to the third case:

```
 insertSpecial 'o' 'l' ('l':"o") = 'l' : insertSpecial 'o' 'l' "o"
```

Now in the last call we're actually binding `'o'` to `a` which is equal to `x` and we land in the second case, where we prepend the value of `y` (`'l'`) to `a` (`'o'`) and `as` (`[]`), so we get:

```
insertSpecial 'o' 'l' ('o':[]) | 'o' == 'o' = 'l' : 'o' : []
```

Putting all these substitutions together we get:

```
insertSpecial 'o' 'l' "helo" = 
'h' : insertSpecial 'o' 'l' "elo" =
'h' : 'e' : insertSpecial 'o' 'l' "lo" = 
'h' : 'e' : 'l' : insertSpecial 'o' 'l' "o" =
'h' : 'e' : 'l' : 'l' : 'o' : []
```

And as described above `'h' : 'e' : 'l' : 'l' : 'o' : [] == ['h','e','l','l','o'] == "hello"`. Yay.

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain a little more. If you have specific questions please ask.

Comment: @MHZ I have edited the answer again and provided an example, hopefully this illustrates a little better what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of splitting at an index, you can split at the first position satisfying a criterion,

```
insertSpecial y x xs = front ++ [y] ++ back
  where
    (front, back) = break (== x) xs
```

If you want an error in case your assumption that `x` is an element of the list is not satisfied,

```
insertSpecial y x xs = case break (== x) xs of
                         (front, back@(_:_)) -> front ++ [y] ++ back
                         _ -> error "Didn't find element"
```

But the direct recursion is a very good solution too.

Answer (score 1):

There are three cases

```
insertSpecial :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insertSpecial _ _ []                 = ?
insertSpecial x y (a:as) | a == x    = ?
                         | otherwise = a : rest
  where rest = ?
```

What happens in each?

The first case is where you know for sure, that the element is not in the list because the list is empty. Then just return that same, empty list.

The next case is where the first element of the list is the element that you are looking for. Then you just need to return that same list, with y prepended.

The last, recursive, case (`otherwise`) is where the first element is not the one you are looking for, but it might still be in the rest of the list. Then you need to prepend `a` to the rest of the list, where the rest of the list is `as` with `y` prepended before the first occurrence of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
insertSpecial::[Int]->Int->Int->[Int]
insertSpecial [] _ _ = []
insertSpecial list a b = concat [if x == a then [b] ++ [x] else [x] | x<-list]
```

inserts b before a

Answer (score 1):

General predicated `beforeEvery` occurrence in terms of a [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))

```
beforeEvery pred y  =  foldr (\ x xs -> if pred x then y : x : xs else x : xs) []
```

Explicitly unwrapped recursive function terminating after the first occurrence

```
before :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
before _    _ []                   = []
before pred y (x : xs) | pred x    = y : x : before pred y xs
                       | otherwise = x : before pred y xs
```

such that

```
beforeElem x y  =  before (== x) y
```

or

```
beforeElem :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
beforeElem x y  =  before (== x) y
```

meaning

```
beforeElem 3 89 [1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5]  ==  [1,2,89,3,4,5,3,4,5]
```